# How do I know an outlier in a time series isn't the beginning of a trend?

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics

I wish to average detections coming in over time.

I use the interquartile range to identify outliers and to discard them. I look at the last 30 values.

What do I do if each new value is an outlier, and hence is discarded? How do I detect that the average has significantly shifted?

I asked a fuller version of this question on [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40575/where-to-start-unevenly-spaced-time-series-with-lots-of-outliers-or-randomness).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a t-test, or similar suitable test depending on your particular distribution. These tests can be used as indicators of whether 2 distributions have the "same" mean. Treating a pair of your measurement sets from different times (say 30 values apart so there's no overlap) as though they come from different distributions will give you a measure of whether the means are significantly different, hence the average has "changed".
If your data is fairly Normal, this should work. If not, you might try reviewing the [t-test wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test). There are some suggestions there of non-parametric techniques to apply in other cases. Those should get you started.